# Don't know why the loop doesn't work (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I just recently started learning Python. Tried to solve a problem where you are given an array of integers and you need to find three of them with the sum closest to target.

My idea was to sort the array and then create two pointers - one at the start of the array, moving right, and one at the end of the array, moving left. And the third pointer is supposed to move along the entire array, while the program calculates and uses the sum of all three of them. But it doesn't work. It ignores some of the indexes.

I feel like if I don't understand this I'll never understand loops in general.

```
nums = [0,1,1,1]
target = 100

nums.sort()
pointer_one = 0
pointer_two = len(nums) - 1
result = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]

while pointer_one < pointer_two:
    for i in nums:
        if i == pointer_one or i == pointer_two:
            pass
        else:
            sum_num = nums[i] + nums[pointer_one] + nums[pointer_two]
            how_close = abs(target - sum_num)
            if how_close < abs(target - result):
                result = sum_num
    pointer_one = pointer_one + 1
    pointer_two = pointer_two - 1
print("Result: ", result)`
```

Comment: `i` is the *value* in the array, not the index.

Comment: Welcome to programming. That feeling never goes away but "I feel like if I don't understand this I'll never understand loops in general." is a bleak sentiment that just isn't true. Our profession is constantly having to learn new stuff and if you're not - you're doing it wrong

Comment: "Omg, I'm an idiot." -> let's rather say your expectations weren't met. This mistake happens to me all the time because I'm so used to how things were in old C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop iterates over the items of the list, but you use it as an index not the actual value.
The standard for loop with an index would in your case look as:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    #rest of your code
```

Look at the docs for examples of both forms of for loops:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: You missed to close a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

When you begin my advice is to use the print() to better understand your code:

iterate over items:

for i in nums:
print(i)

> > > 0 1 1 1

iterate over indexes:

for i in range(len(nums)):
print(i)

> > > 0 1 2 3

Regards